# Google Analytics User explorer export to Google Sheets garbles data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I exported User explorer report to Google Sheets. The data table contained App-instance ID, which is in format 4444444.44444444 (10 letters after dot). Google Sheets detects those cells as type number, and apparently it cannot handle 10 "decimals", but instead it cuts the number to 6 "decimals". It also formats it so that in the cell it shows 0-1 decimals, and all 6 show up in the editing input field when the cell is selected.

Is the situation recoverable at all, or are Google Sheets completely unusable for anything that contains App-instance ID?

Comment: have you tried changing the format of that field to text?

Comment: It doesn't matter what is the format, the cutting of decimals happens before I have a chance to interact with the sheet in any way.

Comment: that's pretty interesting. I would take a look at the importing script then

Comment: I don't think it's possible to access Google Analytics importing script.

Comment: Ah, if you're using the GA export function, then just export into a CSV and then import that to wherever you need.